# What is the dimension of relative Grassmannian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes, grassmannian

Let $E$ be a $r$ rank vector bundle on a smooth projective curve $C$ of genus $g$. Let $G$ denote the Grassmannian of $(r-k)$ rank locally free quotients of $E$.

> A paper by Mukai-Sakai seems to claim that $G$ has dimension = $k(r-k)+1$.

I would like to know an explanation behind the above claim.

> More generally, what is the dimension of the Quot scheme $Quot_{E/X/S}$ of coherent quotients of $E$ which is a fixed coherent sheaf of an $S-$scheme $X$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $E$ is Zariski locally trivial, the relative Grassmannian is covered by charts isomorphic to $U \times \mathrm{Gr}(k,r)$, where $U \subset C$ are open subsets.

Comment: I see. So the "absolute" Grassmannian has dimension $k(r-k)$ and the extra 1 comes from $C$. What about the Quot scheme? There we don't have local triviality.

Comment: For $\mathrm{Quot}$ schemes it is more tricky. But you can usually compute tangent spaces at points and thus bound the dimension.